# Is it possible to clear src results in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have a simple org-mode document:

```
#+TITLE: My Document

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results raw :hlines yes
  return 'hello world!'
#+END_SRC
```

Issuing `C-c C-v C-b` and responding `yes` to the prompt to evaluate the python code block yields

```
#+TITLE: My Document

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results raw :hlines yes
  return 'hello world!'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
hello world!
```

Repeating this command yields

```
#+TITLE: My Document

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results raw :hlines yes
  return 'hello world!'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
hello world!
hello world!
```

My problem is that I don't want the old results kept once I reevaluate my src block. Is there a command to clear the old results?

Comment: It's buggy behaviour. The default is `:results replace`, but replacement doesn't work well with string output. It does work with table output.

Comment: I think you want `:results replace drawer` Or just `:results drawer`

Comment: @Melioratus, Your suggestion seems to work. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @gusbrs - Done! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `:wrap example` might help.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

org-mode provides 2 convenient header options to automatically replace the results when executing a `SRC` block. For contiguous results I recommend option 1. If your results will contain empty lines or your `SRC` block produces org syntax then use option 2.

#### Option 1 - Use `:results replace`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results replace :hlines yes
  return 'hello world!'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: hello world!
```

#### Option 2 - Use `:results replace drawer`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results replace drawer :hlines yes
  return 'hello world!'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:RESULTS:
hello world!
:END:
```

Thank you for posting your question!
Hope that helped!

---

> **This answer was tested using:**
>   GNU Emacs 25.3.1
>   org-mode version: 9.1.13

Comment: +1 But I think the critical part here is the `drawer`. `:results replace` will work the same as `:result value` (default), but the OP wishes a `raw` output, and either `:results replace drawer` or `:results drawer` as in your comment deliver that.

Answer (score 3):

`:results raw` does not keep track of where the results output ends, so as the comments point out, you need to use something other than `raw` if you want org to replace the old results with the new.

There *is* a function to delete results: `org-babel-remove-result` but that is exactly what org uses to replace results, so it suffers from the same limitation.