# How to save org-mode file without results of source code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm preparing a presentation in org-mode and I'd like to demonstrate live the execution of code. So I'd like to start the presentation without any result block.

How can I remove (strip) the results on save?

I [realize](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35537/43747) there's `M-x org-babel-remove-result`. And maybe there's a way to hook this one into `C-x C-s` somehow. But I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this snippet of code to your init file.

```el
(defun my-results-remove-hook ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
      (org-babel-remove-result)))
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'my-results-remove-hook)
```

And rest assured, the result blocks will not get persisted.

Comment: I realize that `org-babel-remove-result` removes the result of the source block at point, but not all results. I use your snippet, but adapt it to call `(org-babel-remove-result-one-or-many "#+RESULT")` - and it works. Thanks!